# Best Practices for Writing Prover and Verifier Circuits for Zero-Knowledge Proof Implementation

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Considering that I am writing a circuit that will take age as input and return true or false.

For this ZKP system, I guess I don't need a separate prover circuit and verifier circuit.

Consider that I am writing a circuit that will take age as input and generate a proof. Now I will write another circuit for a verifier that will take the proof as input and verify whether it is true or false.

I am seeking expert advice on which one is correct or if there are better approaches to implement this. I was curious about the membership proof technique as well.

Comment: This is a Q/A site that also acts as a knowledge base. That means that we do expect that you perform your best to format the question. This includes capitalization and correct punctuation. Please use a language checker if English is not your main language. It would be nice if you'd perform an [edit].